# Where should I place confusion matrix code

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, confusion-matrix

I know there are many codes about drawing a confusion matrix on the internet, but none of them mention where they should be placed.

I don't know whether they should be placed after model.fit_generator,

or inside CustomDataGenerator to generate y_true and y_label, and then receive y_true and y_label after model.fit_generator,

or if they should be placed after model.fit_generator using validation data to generate y_true and y_label for drawing the confusion matrix.

My original idea was to return y_label(return y) within CustomDataGenerator and use y_label to obtain y_true, then call cal to draw the confusion matrix. However, during my attempts, I realized that my approach of y_label,y_true might be incorrect.

```
image_folders = ['image1', 'image2', 'image3', 'image4', 'image6', 'image7']
label_folders = ['label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'label4', 'label6', 'label7']   
data_generator = CustomDataGenerator(image_folders, label_folders, **params)
model = unet()
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('weight/syu/123467_CM_test.hdf5', monitor='loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
train_history=model.fit_generator(data_generator, steps_per_epoch=200,epochs=10,callbacks=[model_checkpoint])

y_true = []  
y_pred = []  

cal(y_true_cm, y_pred_cm)
```

```
class CustomDataGenerator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, image_folders, label_folders,dim=(512,512),  batch_size=1,n_classes=6,n_channels=18,shuffle=True):
        ...
        self.on_epoch_end()
        
    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.image_paths) / self.batch_size))  

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        batch_image_paths = self.image_paths[index * self.batch_size: (index + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_label_paths = self.label_paths[index * self.batch_size: (index + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch = zip(batch_image_paths, batch_label_paths)
        
        return self.get_data(batch)
    
    def on_epoch_end(self):        self.image_paths = []
        self.label_paths = []
        for folder in self.image_folders:
            image_folder_path = os.path.join('data/syu/npy', folder)
            image_files = os.listdir(image_folder_path)
            for file_name in image_files:
                self.image_paths.append(os.path.join(image_folder_path, file_name))

        for folder in self.label_folders:
            ...
                self.label_paths.append(os.path.join(label_folder_path, file_name))

        if self.shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(self.image_paths)
            np.random.shuffle(self.label_paths)

    def get_data(self, batch):
        X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_channels))
        y = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_classes))

        for i, (image_path, label_path) in enumerate(batch):

            image = np.load(image_path)
            label = np.load(label_path)
            
            label_grayscale = np.mean(label, axis=-1)
            
            min_val = label_grayscale.min()
            max_val = label_grayscale.max()
            scaled_label = (label_grayscale - min_val) / (max_val - min_val)  # Scale to [0, 1]
            scaled_label = (scaled_label * (self.n_classes - 1)).astype(int)  # Scale to [0, n_classes-1]
            label_one_hot = to_categorical(scaled_label, num_classes=self.n_classes)

            X[i,] = image
            y[i,] = label_one_hot

        return X, y

    def generate_labels(self, folder):
        ...
    def generate_y_true(self):
        ...

def cal(y_true, y_pred):

    # confusion matrix row means GT, column means predication
    name = '123467_Custom_delete2'
    mat = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
    #'0',
    da = pd.DataFrame(mat, index = [ 'class1', 'class2', 'class3', 'class4', 'class6', 'class7'])
    sns.heatmap(da, annot =True, cbar = None, cmap = 'Blues')
    plt.title(name)
    # plt.tight_layout()yt
    plt.ylabel('True Label')
    plt.xlabel('Predict Label')
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig('{}/{}.png'.format('weight/syu/', name)) 
    plt.close()
```